# counting total calories intake more than

Tags: calories, daily-caloric-intake

I have started following series to build muscle, in [this](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/kris-gethin-building-trainer-nutrition-overview.html) page the calories is 2712, the author says to have 6 meals a day including calories from your workout. Now if i do simple maths as do breakdown of 2712, it is as following

Protein : 241g 
Carbs   : 402g 
Fats    : 71g

---

Total   : 714

But if we do 714*6 = 4,284. That is like double of what he mentioned for training day. Am i doing the maths wrong or there is any typo?

Comment: You're mixing apples with oranges. 1g != 1kcal. 1g of protein/carbs = roughly 4kcal, 1g of fat = roughly 9kcal. On a separate note, I would almost double your fat intake and reduce both protein and carbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 2712 calories is your daily target and not the author's, that is the total daily requirement. Thus 2712 cals / 6 meals = 452 cals/meal.

Comment: That is great, i was multiplying it with 6 meals. One thing more, do we weight before cooking or after?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Some people weight their food after cooking, does it matter? Or one should weight it before cooking.

Comment: Don't over analyze counting every single little calorie. Understand the nutrition in the food you eat, ie cals per serving, protein per serving, carbs per serving, etc., and if you really want to get down to it, you can use measuring cups for measuring out your grains, veggies, etc. A good concept is portions, which a heuristic for a portion is the size of your fist. 1 portion (or fist full) of protein, carbs, veggies.

Answer (score 1):

protein, fat, and carbs all contain a different amount of calories per gram

```
protein = 4
carbs = 4 
fat = 9
```

so your math is:

```
protein : 241 * 4 = 964
carbs : 402 * 4 = 1608
fat: 71 * 9 = 639
```

so total is:

```
964 + 1608 + 639 = 3211
```

If those are the macros, it looks like the math on the site might be off by a bit. If you are new to building, then you probably dont need so much.  Aim for a total of 2800 calories, reduce all three fats, protein, and carbs a bit to fit it and try that out for a month.  Adjust based on the results.